# WCF Multiple Contracts

Tags: wcf, architecture

Could I please get some clarification on a complex WCF service that exposes my business objects. Let's say I have 4 objects: `contact`, `organisation`, `project` and `letter`.

Is the best way to create my service:

1. Make 4 contracts as 'service objects' and pass the object and the intended operation as values/parameters in the 'service object'? or
2. Create contracts for all of the objects and their functions (which could be many)?

Many Thanks,

Chris

Comment: the reason for asking this currently i have all of my functions in one service named like this contact_function1, contact_function2..... organisation_function1, organsiation_function2 and my service file is getting quite long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), you might want to think about splitting those things up.

One typical approach is to have one interface (e.g. one "service") per object type - e.g. one interface for `Contact` with all the operations needed and useful for contacts, etc.

Of course, you might also have methods that deal with multiple different types of objects - those are a bit tricky to place in a specific service contract.

Also, with WCF, you can easily have a single service implementation class that then in turn implements multiple of those interfaces at once - e.g. to use common code or common patterns.

But I guess it would be a good idea to rethink your service contract and convert it into smaller, more manageable chunks.

**Update:**

if your service implementation class implements four service contracts, then you'd have to configure it like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="YourNamespace.YourServiceImplementation">
     <host>
        <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://YourServer/MyServices/" />
        </baseAddresses>
     </host>
     <endpoint name="Contact"
         address="Contact"
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         contract="YourNamespace.IContactService" />
     <endpoint name="Letter"
         address="Letter"
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         contract="YourNamespace.ILetterService" />
     <endpoint name="Organisation"
         address="Organisation"
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         contract="YourNamespace.IOrganisationService" />
     <endpoint name="Project"
         address="Project"
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         contract="YourNamespace.IProjectService" />
     <endpoint name="mex"
         address="mex"
         binding="mexHttpBinding" 
         contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Now, each of your services is available at a specific endpoint:

- your `IContractService` is reachable at `http://YourServer/MyServices/Contact`
- your `ILetterService` is reachable at `http://YourServer/MyServices/Letter`

and so on....

For each of those addresses, you can now add service references from a client - add only those you really need. One app might need only a single of those services, another might need two or three etc.

Comment: thanks for the response marc_s. I have tried seperate interfaces for each object however I am unable to find them when i am using the'Add Service Reference' dialogue box in VS10. I can find my mex endpoint but i can only configure my app.config to show one interface/contract. If i click on the interface i am show a list of its operations which is great but how do i add more then one interface type underneath the service branch of the services treeview in the 'Add Service Reference' dialogue box.

Comment: You will have a single service (implementation) in your service's config file - but each contract can expose a different endpoint (= a different service address). So you could have a single implementation, but expose five different endpoints (on five different addresses) - and Add Service Reference will go against an endpoint, so it'll always show you just the operations from that single contract (e.g. all operations on `Contact`). If you want to use all five or six service contract, you need to add five or six service references (to each of the endpoints)

Comment: i have managed to add more then one contract to a service and all seems to be going according to plan. thanks for the verification. i was messing myself with my understand of what a contract is. its my interface and not an individual operation associated to the interface. I am very happy thank-you for your time

Comment: thanks for the updated post marc. it looks very similar to my .config i hope your answers will help other newbies as it has clarified my view on WCF. I very greatful for yor time.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the very helpful answer by Marc, the interfaces need to be decorated as below and then only we get the chance to add an independent reference to each contract implemented by the service separately.

```
[ServiceContract(Name="Contact", Namespace="YourNamespace.IContactService")]
public interface IContractService
{
   ...
}
```

Similarly for other interfaces

```
[ServiceContract(Name="Letter", Namespace="YourNamespace.ILetterService")]
public interface ILetterService
{
   ...
}
```

Without adding these attributes, I was unable to add separate service refernce to each of the contracts implemented by the common service.